# Show that $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)}{1+x} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \frac6{(k+1)^4}$

Tags: integration

Show that;

> $$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)}{1+x} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \frac6{(k+1)^4}$$

I arrived to the fact that

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)}{1+x} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int_0^1 x^k \ln^3(x)dx$$

But I am unable to continue further.

Comment: Hint: integration by parts.

Comment: I don't know if you are interested but that series has also a nice closed form.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use differentiation under the integral sign. For any $\alpha > 0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha+n}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+\alpha+1}\tag{1}$$
hence by differentiating three times wrt $\alpha$ both sides of $(1)$ we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{\alpha}\log^3(x)}{1+x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{6(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+\alpha+1)^4}\tag{2}$$
and by considering the limit s $\alpha\to 0^+$:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^3(x)}{1+x}\,dx = 6\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^4} = -\frac{21}{4}\zeta(4)=\color{red}{-\frac{7\pi^4}{120}}\tag{3} $$
follows.

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate by parts:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x^k \ln^3(x) \, dx &= \frac{x^{k + 1}}{k + 1} \ln^3 x \big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{k + 1}}{k + 1} 3 \ln^2(x) \frac 1 x \, dx \\
&= -\frac{3}{k + 1} \int_0^1 x^k \ln^2(x) \, dx
\end{align*}

The next application reverses the sign, picks up factor $2/(k + 1)$, and drops the power on the log by $1$. Continue until the log disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $u=-\ln x$ rewrites the integral as $$-\int_0^\infty \frac{u^3e^{-u}du}{1+e^{-u}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\int_0^\infty u^3e^{-\left(k+1\right)u}du.$$ The substitution $v=\left(k+1\right)u$ in $\int_0^\infty v^3 e^{-v}dv=3!=6$ obtains $$\int_0^\infty u^3e^{-\left(k+1\right)u}du=\frac{6}{\left(k+1\right)^4},\,\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x}dx=6\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{\left(k+1\right)^4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We begin with the substitution $$x=\mathrm{e}^{-y}$$ so our integral becomes
\begin{equation}
-\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{3}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{\,y}} \mathrm{d} y
\end{equation}

This integral is a [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) of the function
\begin{equation}
f(y) = \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{\,y}}
\end{equation}
where the Mellin transform is defined as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{M}[f(x](s) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} f(x) \mathrm{d} x
\end{equation}

From [*Tables of Integral Transforms*](http://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechAUTHORS:20140123-101456353) (Bateman Manuscript) Volume 1, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{M}[(\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x} + 1)^{-1}](s) = \frac{1}{\alpha^{s}} \Gamma(s) (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)
\label{eq:1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

With $$s = 4 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \alpha = 1$$ we have
\begin{equation}
-\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{3}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{y}} \mathrm{d} y = -\Gamma(4) (1-2^{1-4}) \zeta(4) = -\frac{7\pi^{4}}{120}
\end{equation}

Thus
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{ln}^{3}(x)}{1+x} \mathrm{d} x = -\frac{7\pi^{4}}{120}
\end{equation}

### Addendum

We can rewrite \eqref{eq:1} as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}[(\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x} + 1)^{-1}](s) & = \frac{1}{\alpha^{s}} \Gamma(s) (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s) \\
& = \frac{1}{\alpha^{s}} \Gamma(s) \eta(s)
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}
\end{equation}
is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), also known as the alternating Riemann zeta function.

Note that for [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), $\eta(s)$ defaults to the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function). To obtain the Dirichlet eta function type "dirichlet eta(s)".

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=e^{-u}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log^3(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{u^3}{1+e^{-u}}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^ku^3e^{-ku}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty u^3e^{-u}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^4}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=3!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^4}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x} & =
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\partiald[3]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x =
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\partiald[3]{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu} - x^{\mu + 1} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\
\half\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\partiald[3]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu/2 - 1/2}\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{\mu/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\half\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\partiald[3]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\half\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\partiald[3]{}{\mu}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu + 2 \over 2} - \Psi\pars{\mu + 1 \over 2}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the *Digamma Function*. In $\ds{\pars{1}}$ we used the
identity:
$\ds{\Psi\pars{\xi} = -\gamma + \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{\xi - 1} \over 1 - t}
\,\dd \xi}$ with $\ds{\Re\pars{\xi} > 0}$.

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x} & =
{1 \over 16}\bracks{\Psi'''\pars{1} - \Psi'''\pars{\half}} =
\color{#f00}{-\,{7 \over 120}\,\pi^{4}} \approx -5.6822
\end{align}

> Some values of $\ds{\Psi'''}$ [are well known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15):
>   $\ds{\Psi'''\pars{1} = 3! \times \zeta\pars{4} = {1 \over 15}\,\pi^{4}\,,\qquad
> \Psi'''\pars{\half} = 3! \times 15 \times \zeta\pars{4} = \pi^{4}}$
>   
> with
>   $\ds{\zeta\pars{4} = {1 \over 90}\,\pi^{4}}$.